# Python Error Checking Script is Super Slow

Tags: python

I have the following program that has been running for about two hours and has maybe 1/4 more to go.  My questions are below the code:

```
import csv

input_csv = "LOCATION_ID.csv"
input2 = "CITIES.csv"
output_csv = "OUTPUT_CITIES.csv"

with open(input_csv, "rb") as infile:
    input_fields = ("ID", "CITY_DECODED", "CITY", "STATE", "COUNTRY", "SPELL1", "SPELL2", "SPELL3")
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile, fieldnames = input_fields)
    with open(input2, "rb") as infile2:
        input_fields2 = ("Latitude", "Longitude", "City")
        reader2 = csv.DictReader(infile2, fieldnames = input_fields2)
        next(reader2)
        words = []
        for next_row in reader2:
            words.append(next_row["City"])

        with open(output_csv, "wb") as outfile:
            output_fields = ("EXISTS","ID", "CITY_DECODED", "CITY", "STATE", "COUNTRY", "SPELL1", "SPELL2", "SPELL3")
            writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames = output_fields)
            writer.writerow(dict((h,h) for h in output_fields))
            next(reader)
            for next_row in reader:
                search_term = next_row["CITY_DECODED"]

                #I think the problem is here where I run through every city
                #in "words", even though all I want to know is if the city
                #in "search_term" exists in "words
                for item in words:
                    if search_term in words:
                        next_row["EXISTS"] = 1

                writer.writerow(next_row)
```

I have a few questions here:

**1**  Given that input_csv has 14k rows and input2 has only 6k rows, why does this take so long? I understand that the inner-most for loop (beginning "for item in words:") is inefficient (see qtn 3), but I'm hoping for more of an intuitive/image of what is happening behind the scenes so that I (and hopefully other SO-users) can avoid make this same mistake on other of our programs.

**2** If I want this code to continue to run, how does this relate to my leaving the computer and it going to sleep/hibernating?  Will the program stop at that point, but start up again on its own when the computer is in use again?  I'm really wondering how the compiler once running a program interacts with the operating system and what is means for a computer to "go to sleep" as it relates to a python program.

**and 3** What is a more efficient implementation of this code?  I'm not wrong in thinking it shouldn't take more than a few minutes to do this, right?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with one spot of inefficiency I see:

```
for next_row in reader:
                search_term = next_row["CITY_DECODED"]
                for item in words:
                    if search_term in words:
                        next_row["EXISTS"] = 1
```

That's 14k iterations of the outer `for` loop. Then, roughly 6k iterations *each time* in the nested `for` loop. Then *more* iterations when you do `if search_term in words`, because it iterates over words until it returns.

I haven't put too much thought into what this algorithm is actually doing, but you should at the very least remove duplicates in `words` (ie, `words = list(set(words))`).

I was about to post about that little `for item in words` loop. It was confusing me as to why you did that as `items` is never used and so the for loop is a big waste of time.

It most likely can be reduced to:

```
for next_row in reader:
    search_term = next_row["CITY_DECODED"]
    if search_term in words:
        next_row["EXISTS"] = 1
    writer.writerow(next_row)
```

So, let's sum up all the iterations you had:

~6k for `for next_row in reader2: words.append(next_row["City"])`

~14k iterations of `for next_row in reader:` MULTIPLIED by the sum(i,1,6000) which is about 252 billion.

Taking out the extraneous loop gives you around 84 million iterations which is.. well, much better.

Comment: There aren't duplicates in either file

Comment: I guess that extra for loop making 6k extra iterations 14k times was doing it.  Even then though I would have thought it would only add a fraction of a second extra per row, though...

Comment: well, it was the difference between 84 million and 504 billion iterations (worst case)

Comment: Actually, I guess it's roughly 252 billion iterations since it's 14,000*(sum(i,1,6000).